# motd for each ip address is not working

Tags: shell-script, motd

In Ubuntu, I added file under /etc/update-motd.d/

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d ' ' -f 1)

if [ "$IP" = 172.16.20.10 ];    then 
    printf "\nHi Frank\n"
elif [ "$IP" = 172.16.20.20 ];  then 
    printf "\nHi, Eliot. Nice to see you!!\n"
else
    printf "\nWho are you?\n"
fi
```

It does not working because `echo $SSH_CONNECTION` had not ready when motd executed.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You may be able to change the file on each login via the sshd `ForceCommand` option or PAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.... the motd is a static file... Ubuntu has an update-motd tool which periodically regenerates this file, but there is no way to do anything related to a connection using the motd.

You can probably include something equivalent in the /etc/profile... which is run after someone logs in.